# Maclaurin series, find the tenth derivative

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, taylor-expansion

The problem is as follows: Find the Maclaurin series of $$\begin{cases} \frac{\sin(x)}{x},& x \neq 0 \\ 1,& x=0 \end{cases}$$ and then find $f^{10}(0)$.

I figured out the series, if $x\neq 0$ then it is $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}$$ but I have a question about the tenth derivative.

I know how to find it in the typical Maclaurin series, but because the definition of the function says that if $x=0, f(x)=1$. Does that mean that $f^{(10)}(0)=1$ too? If no, can I have a quick clue, what should I do?

Comment: Just look at the coefficient of $x^{10}$. $\frac {f^{(10)} (0)} {(10)!}=\frac {(-1)^{5}} {(11)!}$.

Comment: Yes i know but i got confused about the part of the definition of f(x), because we are looking for the tenth derivative at x = 0 and the function is defined by 1 in case of x = 0. Wondered if the definition plays a part in finding the 10th derivative or not.

Comment: $f(0)=1$ is needed to make sure that $f$ is smooth and it has  Series expansion around $0$.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you so much! :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expansion at 0 means that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k+1)!} 
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k$$
and due to the identity theorem for power series, the coefficients at each $x^k$ will match.  This means particular for the coefficient of $x^{10}$ that:

$$\frac{f^{(10)}(0)}{10!} = \frac{(-1)^5}{11!}$$

Comment: You missed $(-1)^{5}$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: oops, fixed it.